# calling selectors in .mm but not in .h file

Tags: objective-c, xcode, selector

I wanted to check my understanding of what's going in this example regarding selectors:

Suppose I have an `NSArray` of `Foo` objects called arr in Bar.m. In Foo.m, I have a `(NSComparisonResult)compareFoo:` method, but I forget to declare in the Foo.h file. Yet, when I call `[arr sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compareFoo:)];` the code runs fine. Is this because the message `compareFoo:` is getting sent to the objects in the array, which are `Foo` objects, so they can call `compareFoo:` even if it's not declared in Foo.h?

Wasn't 100% sure about this and got curious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C has dynamic typing, which means you can send a message to instances of an object without declaring it in the interface or .h file.  The way you do this is through selectors.

Selectors don't have compile time checks.  That is why sometimes you get runtime errors about a method not existing on an object, when you declare a selector in correctly.